# How to make jmeter reach target throughput or fail trying?

Tags: jmeter, stress-testing

I have a very simple web service and I'm trying to measure its latency metrics under different throughputs -

[image]

If the system under test can't handle the target throughput, **I want Jmeter to keep the same throughput, even if a lot of requests fail.**

I tried implementing this using a large number of threads and a constant throughput timer, but Jmeter tended to simply not reach the target throughput instead of requests failing.

Any recommendations?

Comment: May I know the ramp-up time in your test plan? To achieve the volume, you need to craft ramp-up carefully? Also, please share the error details. Thanks!

Comment: My rampup time is ~users/10. I did not craft it carefully.

The errors I expect from my web service are "Connection timed out" or "503 Service Unavailable" for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constant Throughput Timer has 2 main limitations:

1. It is accurate enough on **minute** level so you need to ensure that your test is running long enough (minute or more). Also its effect is not immediate so during 1st minute of your load test you need to control virtual users arrival rate using Ramp-Up Period setting on [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level
2. Constant Throughput Timer is only capable of **pausing** the threads to **limit** their execution rate to the "target throughput", it will not be able to kick off any extra threads so make sure you define enough virtual users again on Thread Group level

---

Given Web service == HTTP transport and HTTP being stateful protocol (each JMeter thread (virtual user) will wail for response from the previous [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler prior to starting next one you can speed things up by defining a **timeout** for your HTTP Requests so they would fail earlier. The best place to put the timeouts is [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults), this way you will be able to do it in a single shot for all HTTP Request samplers in scope

[image: JMeter HTTP Request Defaults Timeout]

---

You may also want to try [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) which is a little bit enhanced version of the Constant Throughput Timer.

Comment: Timeout is a great solution. Thanks!